# How can I have one systemd service trigger another after it completes?

Tags: systemd

I have two processes that need to run under different conditions (Service1 has to be run from a specific TTY and service2 cannot be run under that TTY.) so they have to be run from different systemd services.  But I want them to run back to back.  So I want to trigger just service1 with a timer but then I want service2 to be triggered right after service1.

Is there a graceful way to achieve this?

Service1

```
[Unit]
Description=blank the cursor

[Service]
StandardInput=tty-force 
StandardOutput=tty 
TTYPath=/dev/tty1 
Type=simple 
ExecStart=tput civis > /dev/tty1
```

Service2

```
[Unit]
Description=random wallpaper change script

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=wallpaper.sh
User=deanresin
Type=simple 
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/deanresin/scripts/wallpaper.sh
```

I want service1 to trigger service2 after it completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> service1 to trigger service2 after it completes

You could achieve this relationship from service1, or you could achieve it from service2.

To achieve it in service1

```
[Unit]
Before=service2.service
Wants=service2.service # Start service2 after this service
```

To achieve it from service2

```
[Unit]
After=service1.service
BindsTo=service1.service # Only starts if service1 exits with success

[Install]
WantedBy=service1.service # Creates a Wants dependency in service1
```

Source systemd unit manual:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: WantedBy is invalid under Unit: "Unknown key name 'WantedBy' in section 'Unit', ignoring"

Comment: This answer is incorrect. [Unit] sections don't allow the WantedBy key, and the docs even say this: _Note: WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, and UpheldBy= are used in the [Install] section to create symlinks in .wants/, .requires/, and .upholds/ directories. They cannot be used directly as a unit configuration setting._

Answer (score 2):

[The Arch Linux wiki used to suggest the following to trigger the reload of the HTTP server after certbot renew](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Certbot&oldid=496329#systemd):

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl reload nginx.service
```

I'll not say this is "graceful" but adding the following to `service1.service` can do what you would like to do:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/systemctl start service2.service
```